# How to install laravel 5.6 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-5, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I upgraded `PHP 7.0` to `7.1` with this command:

```
1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

and ran this command from `laravel.com`:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

After ran this code, got following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I run this command:
    sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1

afetr run `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` command, show error:

```
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check    https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                     
Your configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Have you tried installing ext-mbstring ?

Comment: There is not installed php-mbstring, try to install it using: `sudo apt-get install php7.*-mbstring`

Comment: @HirenGohel , Hi, please check my question :-(

Comment: Try to run: `sudo composer self-update` and `sudo composer clear-cache`

Comment: @mySun: Is it works?

Comment: @HirenGohel , I run this code but after `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` command, show this error: `Could not read /home/shayvard/.composer/auth.json                                                
  file_get_contents(/home/shayvard/.composer/auth.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied ` :-(

Comment: This is permission issue. Try that command with `sudo`, like: `sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: I use sudo but show `Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. error` :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to,

**Install `mbstring`:**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1
```

and then,

**Restart your server:**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
or
sudo service nginx restart
```

**To solve the error with composer, run:**

```
sudo composer self-update

sudo composer clear-cache

sudo composer config -g secure-http false
```

Comment: Hi, Run `sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring` and then `sudo service apache2 restart` but the same error is shown :(

Comment: @mySun if that does not work then run `phpenmod mbstring` followed by `apachectl graceful`

Comment: Thank you, But show other error! please check my question :-(

Comment: Thank you, but show this error !: `Could not read /home/shayvard/.composer/auth.json                                                
  file_get_contents(/home/shayvard/.composer/auth.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied ` :-(

Comment: @mySun use `sudo`

Comment: I use `sudo` but show `Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` error :-(

Comment: @mySun  Please post another question with the new problem you have that way even others will be able to help you. It is unwise to discuss in the comments.  And don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: tanks, sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for laravel installation:

**Install composer**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

After installation, on typing `composer` in terminal you'll get
[image: composer]

**Laravel Basic Requirements:**

If you are not using Homestead, you will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:

- PHP >= 7.3
- BCMath PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- Fileinfo PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension  `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension `sudo apt-get install php-xml`

**Install Laravel**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name
```

After laravel gets installed, assign permission to your `storage, bootstrap` folder as like bellow:

```
sudo chmod  -R 777 storage  

sudo chmod  -R 777 bootstrap
```

Now your project is ready to run, using serve command:

```
 php artisan serve
```

Check detailed documentation check [laravel-installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation)

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-common php-mbstring php-xmlrpc php-soap php-gd php-xml php-mysql php-cli php-mcrypt

This will install all php extensions required for Laravel.